# Can't login using OpenID on StackOverflow.com but works on Meta?

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-overflow, openid, login

I have recently changed my OpenID provider to WordPress. I'm using the same ID but the provider has changed. Everything works fine when authenticating with sites like meta.stackoverflow.com and getsatisfaction.com. But I can't access my account on stackoverflow.com. I enter 'johan.andersson.net' or 'http://johan.andersson.net' in the OpenID url field and click 'Log in'. On meta.stackoverflow.com I get to the login page in a timely fashion but on stackoverflow.com all browsers (I've tested with) just hangs.
After a while I got a '504 Gateway Time-Out' when using IE (@ https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate).

I've also tested my OpenID at test-id.net and it works. Thought it was something wrong with my new OpenId provider but it seems it is stackoverflow.com which has troubles communicating with the idp?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this -- perhaps some temporary network issue 7 hours ago?

Comment: Very strange, now it works on both sites! Thanks for looking into this so quickly.